# Custom validation to compare time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Trying to get my model to validate time, I.e the end time is > the start time or if one is populated then so must the other.

So far I have:

**Model**

```
    public int ID { get; set; }        
    [DataType(DataType.Time, ErrorMessage = "Incorrect format or missing date")]
    [DisplayName("MondayStart")]
    public DateTime? MondayStart { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time, ErrorMessage = "Incorrect time")]
    [DisplayName("MondayEnd")]
    [GreaterThanAtt("MondayStart", "MondayEnd", ErrorMessage = "Incorrect format or missing date")]
```

**GreaterThanAtt class**

```
    using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;

namespace OrwellFrontEnd.CompareAtt
{
    public class GreaterThanAtt : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public DateTime _End { get; set; }
        public DateTime _Start { get; set; }

        public GreaterThanAtt (string Start, string End)
        {
            _Start = DateTime.ParseExact(Start, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //Convert.ToDateTime(Start);
            _End = DateTime.ParseExact(End, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // Convert.ToDateTime(End);
            //return DateTime.Compare(this._End, Convert.ToDateTime(_Start)) > 0;                      

        }
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if (value != null && DateTime.Compare(_End, _Start) > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**View**

```
<div style="display: table-row;">
                <div class="div-label-text" , style="display: table-cell"> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MondayStart) </div>
                <div class="div-EditorFor" , style="display: table-cell"> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MondayStart, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "div-form-control", id = "txtMondayStart" } }) </div>
                <div class="div-val-cell" , style="display: table-cell"> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MondayStart, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) </div>
                <div class="div-label-text" , style="display: table-cell"> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MondayEnd) </div>
                <div class="div-EditorFor" , style="display: table-cell"> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MondayEnd, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "div-form-control", id = "txtMondayEnd" } }) </div>
                <div class="div-val-cell" , style="display: table-cell"> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MondayEnd, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) </div>
            </div>
```

Not sure if the code would work, but now it has changed the view page so when I go to enter time its a free text..

Previously it would display a --:-- to enter time but that has gone from the End date and it wants you to enter a date time.

Comment: Your attribute wont work because your trying to parse the text "MondayStart" and "MondayEnd" to a `DateTime` (not the value of their properties). And you don't need to pass "MondayEnd" anyway since that is the property your validating. Suggest you work through [this tutorial](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: Based on this, I thought if you pass the display name in of another attribute it would pass the value in..

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/220025/A-sample-on-Asp-Net-MVC-Model-Validation-using-Dat

Do you know for absolute certainty that it is wrong?

I'm new to this, sorry have a lot to learn.

Comment: Absolutely certain it wont work - to get a value you would need something like `var otherProperty = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(OtherProperty);` Have a look at the link I gave you

Comment: Thanks I tried this and it sort of worked in the sense that it stopped the form progressing but no validation was shown.  I think this was because of the way i have everythying setup, if i can link it to show Remote works i might be able to do it :)

Comment: You can always use a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[GreaterThan]` attribute.